# how set title linespace precisely

Tags: line-spacing

Background: I want to design my own thesis class file, to be just like the Word style and Word title. It then has the following requirements:

- for `chapter` title ，fontsize= `16bp`，weight=`\bfseries`，linespacing=`singlespace`
- for the `section` title，fontsize= `14bp`，alignment=`raggedright`，linespacing=`singlespace`
- for the `subsection` title ，fontsize=`12bp`，alignment=`raggedright`，linespacing=`singlespace`

and the remainder has linespace=`22bp` and fontsize=`12bp`

This is my MWE，the `ctexbook` is a Chinese file，just put it as `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}`，I know that title package will do it，how can I setting?

But i use the the `ctex` package

```
 \ctexset{chapter/name={第,章},
chapter/format={\bfseries \heiti \centering \zihao{3}},
  chapter/beforeskip={32bp},  
  chapter/afterskip={16bp},
  chapter/fixskip = true,
  }
  \ctexset{section={
    format={\raggedright \bfseries \heiti \zihao{4}},
    beforeskip=28bp,
    afterskip=14bp,
    fixskip = true,
    }
}
\ctexset{subsection={
   format={\bfseries \heiti \raggedright \zihao{-4}},
   beforeskip=24bp,
   afterskip=12bp,
   fixskip = true,
    }
\ctexset{subsubsection={
      format={\raggedright\zihao{-4}},
    beforeskip=24bp,
     afterskip=12bp,
    fixskip = true,
    }
}
```

Comment: Put what as `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}`? If you can set your MWE up to use `book`, all to the good. Otherwise, stick to what you need. Either way, please provide something we can compile. Just out of curiosity, if you really want it to look just like Word, why are you trying to do it in LaTeX? Surely that's the worst of both worlds: user-challenging input and typographically-challenged output.

Comment: Does Word really do font sizes in `bp` rather than `pt`? Note that font sizes, at least in the TeX world, are not absolute. How large `12pt` is depends on the font. I've never seen requirements specified in big points, though. It looks as if the class you are using has its own way of customising the section titles, so you should use its interface.

Comment: thank you，just design my own thesis using tex ，but not Word. as you know almost all the school has the style requirement using word, i just convert it to latex, so it is my purpose design the cls file for the template.in the word, fonsize use pound unit. so in latex i use bp instead of that

Comment: What's a pound unit in font size? Note that single spacing in LaTeX, in the standard classes, at least, is not single spacing in Word.